# Advice and help if there is shorter way to write code for this task

Tags: java

I recently started to get into Java (about a week ago) and I have a question for the code bellow:
The program written checks if the input number from a user (whole number) can be divided on both 5 and 7, only by 5, only by 7 and if it cannot be divided at all.
My question is, is there some other way to reduce the code written?
First post here, sorry if I ask dumb question, I am just curious.
Thank you in advance.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    int five = 5;
    int seven = 7;
    boolean a = (number % five == 0) && (number % seven == 0);
    if (a == true)
    {
        System.out.println(number + " divides on both 5 and 7.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(number + " doesn't divide on both 5 and 7.");
    }
    if (number % five == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(number + " divides successfuly by 5.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(number + " can't be divided successfuly by 5.");
    }
    if (number % seven == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(number +" divides successfuly by 7.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(number + " can't be divided successfuly by    7.");
    }
```

Comment: This is not "optimization," optimization refers to improving the speed of an algorithm, not reducing the amount of code you have to write. Sadly, these usually work in opposition to each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course. What you need to do is nest if statements.

```
int number = sc.nextInt();
if (number % five == 0)
{
    if (number % seven == 0)
        System.out.println(number + " is divisible by both 5 and 7.");
    else
        System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 5.");
}
else {
    if (number % seven == 0)
        System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 7.");
    else
        System.out.println(number + " is not divisible by either 5 or 7.");
}
```

This means that any code inside the curly braces of the first if statement can only be reached if `number%five == 0`. Therefore, after that point, there are two possibilities: either it is divisible by 7 as well or it is not.

Likewise, code in the first else can only be reached if `number%five != 0`. Therefore, after that point, there are two possibilities: either it is divisible by 7 or it is divisible by neither of them.

Comment: Your way makes me understand better the logic (atleast I think so), thank you for the explanation, it helped alot :)

Comment: @Kristiyian No problem. By the way, it's helpful to mark this answer as your accepted answer in case any future readers stumble across this question and want to know how you solved it.